# How to provide Animation in Fragments for Android 3.1

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

I have created a demo app in android 3.1 using fragmnets. Now I want to provide some good animation in it. I have tried the followwing code:

```
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
```

But it does make no change.

Please help me.